# \r\n in a string not accepted on database

Tags: database, oledb, foxpro, dbf

I create a string variable for an Update SQL command in order to execute this command to a dbf file ( with OleDb).

When my SQL Command contain in a string  \r\n the SqlCommand is not accepted :(

**Here is an example of my SQL Command :**

```
update ZZAg7eve set evenotes = 'line1\r\nline2' where eveNum = '00000003'
```

I know that the problem is \r\n.
I tried to use a verbatim, but there is always the same error : "Command contains unreconized phrase/keywords".

Comment: How do you know the the `\r\n` is the problem?

Comment: cause if i remove it, the SQL command is executed whitout any problems

Answer (score 1):

In VFP, you use CHR(13) + CHR(10) to indicate CRLF. So try:

```
update ZZAg7eve set evenotes = 'line1' + chr(13) + chr(10) + 'line2' where eveNum = '00000003'
```